# Sort values in ascending groups representing every third value

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, sorting, grouping

I have an array that I'd like to reorder by every 3rd item. So it's 1st, 4th, 7th and then 2nd, 5th, 8th and 3rd, 6th, 9th.

Input:

```
$items = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
```

Desired result:

```
['1','4','7','2','5','8','3','6','9']
```

Or it can be 3 separate arrays as well. Like this:

`['1', '4', '7']`
`['2', '5', '8']`
`['3', '6', '9']`

I tried `array_chunk($items, count($items) / 3)` but it just returns the same array divided into 3 equal arrays.

`['1', '2', '3']`
`['4', '5', '6']`
`['7', '8', '9']`

I don't know if I should use `array_chunk` and then something else to achieve what I want.

UPDATE: It does not have to be exactly 9 items in the input array. it can be shorter or longer, the key point is that it has to take every 3rd item as long as it finds any and so on...

So if there are 10 items:

```
$items = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'];
```

Desired result:

```
['1','4','7','10','2','5','8','3','6','9']
```

Comment: Is the array always exactly 9 items long, or is there a rule for what shorter or longer arrays should look like?

Comment: @IMSoP Not exactly 9 items, I just used it for a reference. The key point is 3rd item. So even if there are 5 items for example it should order it like this:  1, 4, 2, 5, 3. I don't even know if this is possible :D

Comment: Is the example input array always "sorted" or thats just for example sake?

Comment: @mardubbles always sorted

Comment: use array_values

Comment: @Dave How should output be with not even chunked elements? Is chunk size always 3? How it should look like with 10th element then?

Comment: @Justinas if there is the 10th element it should be the like this: 1,4,7,10,2......

Comment: So if the array is `$items = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10);` where do you want the 10 placed

Comment: @RiggsFolly ```array('1','4','7','10','2','5','8','3','6','9')```

Comment: for more values of initial $items you should post the right question ...

Comment: @Constantin oops :D sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to loop over the list three times:

- Start at element 0, skipping by 3, stop when past end of list
- Start at element 1, skipping by 3, stop when past end of list
- Start at element 2, skipping by 3, stop when past end of list

That can be easily achieved using C-style [for loop syntax](https://php.net/for):

```
$maxKey = count($items) - 1;
$rearrangedItems = [];
for ( $key=0; $key<=$maxKey; $key+=3 ) {
    $rearrangedItems[] = $items[$key];
}
for ( $key=1; $key<=$maxKey; $key+=3 ) {
    $rearrangedItems[] = $items[$key];
}
for ( $key=2; $key<=$maxKey; $key+=3 ) {
    $rearrangedItems[] = $items[$key];
}
```

If you needed to generalize to different offsets, you could put the whole thing into an outer loop rather than copying and pasting:

```
$offset = 3;
$maxKey = count($items) - 1;
$rearrangedItems = [];
for ( $start=0; $start<$offset; $start++ ) {
    for ( $key=$start; $key<=$maxKey; $key+=$offset ) {
        $rearrangedItems[] = $items[$key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$items = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$tmp = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    $tmp[$i%3][] = $items[$i];
}
$result = array_merge($tmp[0], $tmp[1], $tmp[2]);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: A brief explanation of how this works would be good, so that readers can see how to adapt the technique to different situations.

Comment: @IMSoP this one works as great as the example you provided. But this one uses just one for loop instead of 2 in your example

Comment: I dont think @IMSoP was complaining about your code, just that you supply no information about Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: I like this code though. But because there is no explanation I'm going to accept @IMSoP 's answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$items = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
$tmp = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($items); $i++) {
    $tmp[$i%3][] = $items[$i];
}
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $tmp);
dd($result);
```

Output :

array('1','4','7','2','5','8','3','6','9')

Comment: A brief explanation of how this works would be good, so that readers can see how to adapt the technique to different situations.

Answer (score 1):

I see this task as nothing more than a sorting task.

Sort each value by it modulus value when divided by 3.  If the result is 0, then fallback to 3.  Nothing extravagant, just simple, direct, logical, D.R.Y. programming.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h7kk3))

```
array_multisort(
    array_map(fn($v) => $v % 3 ?: 3, $items),
    $items
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward:

```php
$items = array('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');

$items = array_chunk($items, 3); # Split into arrays of size 3
$items = array_map(null, ...$items); # Transpose the arrays
$items = array_merge(...$items); # Merge the arrays again

print_r($items);
```

Comment: There will be empty values if there not even chunk sizes, e.g. add one more element to array

Comment: yeah, @Justinas is right, if I add another item, there will be 2 other items with value equal to ```null```

Comment: A brief explanation of how this works would be good, so that readers can see how to adapt the technique to different situations.